# Join column/foreign key value is not passed to nested object with cascade property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two `tables/entities` A and B. A has it's auto generator key which is a primary key. B has it's auto generator key which is a primary key. `Tables/entities` A and B are joined by `A.id(auto generator key)`. I have added `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` in A. I'm getting below exception When I do `save(A)` on A's repository.

Hibernate:

`insert into B (b1, b2, b3, a1) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`

SQL Error:

> 1048, SQLState: 23000 Column 'a1' cannot be null

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B")

public class B {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer b1;
private String b2;
private String b3;
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "a1", referencedColumnName = "a1")
private A a;

public B() {
    super();
}

public B(...) {
    super();
// all argument constructor
}
//regular setter and getters
```

Comment: Can you show us your B Entity class?

Comment: Shared B entity class

Comment: Add also `A` and the code how you try to persist, the you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)